# Insert image to database from a JSON with Web API 2

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

Hello everyone I'm creating an application in Angular 6 where the user fills his data such as name, last name, address and 4 images of their business. All these information is being sent as a JSON:

```
{
  "Name": "string",
  "Lastname": "string",
  "Address": "string",
  "SellersPermit": File,
  "DriversLicense": File,
  "InteriorPhoto": File,
  "ExteriorPhoto": File
}
```

I'm creating this with entity framework, my model is the following:

```
public class SignupEntryItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public byte[] image1 { get; set; }
    public byte[] image2 { get; set; }
    public byte[] image3 { get; set; }
    public byte[] image4 { get; set; }
}
```

The text fields are being inserted perfectly but with the images I get `"error reading string. unexpected token: startobject. path"`

Here's my controller which just receives the data and sends it to the method I defined in anotherclass:

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("AddCustomer")]
        [SwaggerResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, Type = typeof(bool))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddSignup([FromBody] SignupEntryItem signup)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            try
            {
                var result = await _processor.AddCustomer(signup);
                return Ok(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message + "\r\n" + ex.InnerException?.Message);
            }
    }
```

Here's the addCustomer method that receives the signup information:

```
 public async Task<bool> AddCustomer(SignupEntryItem signupEntry)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(signupEntry);
            db.SignupEntryItem.Add(signupEntry);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated, also here's the image of the error I receive:[image]

Comment: Send the ID in json also, doesn't matter what number just add one

Comment: @MarcusHöglund That's not the problem, as I said erverything is inserting right, but the images.. file format is my issue.